# After implementing new template in opencart,homepage slideshow not view

Tags: php, smarty

In default theme all are fine and showing the homepage slideshow,but implementing other theme not showing the homepage slideshow.Checked the admin panel,there are all exactly same as default theme.How to show the slider?

theme/module/Slideshow.tpl

```
<div class="slideshow">
  <div id="slideshow<?php echo $module; ?>" class="nivoSlider">
    <?php foreach ($banners as $banner) { ?>
    <?php if ($banner['link']) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $banner['link']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" /></a>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" />
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slideshow<?php echo $module; ?>').nivoSlider();
});
--></script>
```

slideshow modules are not viewed any kind of images.when `<?php echo $slideshow;?>`.its showing array().

header.tpl

```
<?php $slideshow = $modules->getModules('slideshow'); ?>
            <?php if(count($slideshow)) { ?>
            <!-- Slider -->
            <div id="slider" class="<?php if($theme_options->get( 'slideshow_layout' ) == 2) { echo 'fixed'; } else { echo 'full-width'; } ?>">
                <div class="background-slider"></div>
                <div class="background">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="pattern">
                        <?php foreach($slideshow as $module) { ?>
                        <?php echo $module; ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Which version of OC you are using ?

Comment: You have to go under system->design->layout there would be home page layout, edit it & assign your slideshow module to content top position. I hope it will be worked for you.

Comment: i have already done this job.but its not working.In default template all are working fine.but when i tried other template the problem are rising.Help me please.

Comment: can you please go the content_top.tpl & print variable $modules & post that output here ?

Comment: now its showing the slider image. in array the sider images are viewed. like Array ( [0] =>image1 image2 image3).Now tell me what should i?

Comment: can you please show me the code or your printed array what you get in which file so I can suggest you what should you have to do.

Comment: This is the code of content_top.tpl
<?php print_r($modules);die();
foreach ($modules as $module) { ?>
<?php echo $module; ?>
<?php } ?>

Comment: You should have to print any variable in slider controller file then check the control actually execute this file or not.

Comment: Yup .. if its executed then try to track tpl file for this module

Comment: alreday tried ,when i print print_r($data['module']);die(); showing the images array.

Comment: Is there any error in console, or it would be great if you can share your website link with me

Comment: check all the files and sql  ->https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B46kHIl-4AA5NWF4ODFWZHNrTGs/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for share code with me, You are missed to define content_top area in your theme, you have to go here

```
catalog/view/theme/yourtheme/template/common/home.tpl
```

go to line no 18 & add this line just below the line 18

```
<?php echo $content_top; ?>
```

and your slider will come on your home page.